# Symfony NelmioApiDocBundle filter input type Upload

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I try to display an upload with Nelmio, but the result is always a simple input string.

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="upload images",
 *  filters={
 *      {"name"="observation", "dataType"="file"},
 *      {"name"="signature_tech", "dataType"="file"},
 *      {"name"="signature_chef", "dataType"="file"},
 *  }
 * )
 *
 * @Route("/upload/images", name="api_logout", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function uploadImageAction(Request $request)
```

What is wrong with this code snippet?

Comment: Which version of `NelmioApiDoc` are you using?

Comment: You hace put it under filters, could be that is should be a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Carlos suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994592/symfony-nelmioapidocbundle-filter-input-type-upload/45525038#comment65379680_38994592), you have to put it under filters.